# Connecting Power BI to S3 bucket without using Athena ODBC driver or Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-s3, powerbi-desktop

My data is stored in S3 bucket mostly in .csv and .parquet format. As a user I will have only information about S3 bucket name and Object name. Currently I am doing it using Python script

```
import boto3
import pandas

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id="key_id", aws_secret_access_key="sec_key", aws_session_token="token", region_name='region')
client = session.client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="sdktestbucket2", Key="foo/bar.csv")

df = pd.read_csv(response['Body'])
```

Is there any other alternate way than this to connect Power BI to S3 ?
In my case I need to automate this process.

Comment: Why not Athena? Redshift is a database, it has nothing to do with the question. S3 itself has a REST API and each file is accessible through its URL. You could create a shareable link for those files and read them from Power BI. I suspect what you really want though is getting all the files in a bucket